# audioCodec doesn't recognize 'aac' or 'libfdk-aac'

Tags: ffmpeg, aac

I want to convert mp3 to aac using ffmpeg and stream it to s3 in my node application. My code is as below. Now when I try to use audioCodec as 'aac' or 'libfdk-aac'. It throws the error. Note that ffmpeg is compiled with 'libfdk-aac' and working fine from command line.

Any inputs/fixes ?

```
var proc = new ffmpeg({source:uploadedFiles[0].fd})
.audioCodec('aac') // .audioCodec('libfdk-aac')
.audioChannels(1);

proc.on('error', function(err) { 
console.log('An error occurred: ' + err.message);
})
.on('end', function() {
    console.log('audio uploaded successfully!');
}).pipe(upload(opts));
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the actual error?

Answer (score 1):

The encoder is named `libfdk_aac`, not `libfdk-aac`. Replace the hyphen (`-`) with an underscore (`_`).